# CRM 2011 Localization rendering issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, after activating a language different from English and then click on some drop-down menu the page is not rendered correctly - see the image. This is with Bulgarian language, I have reports that the same issue occurs with French also.

Any suggestions about what the problem is or how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you got it under control or does the issue remain?

Comment: What's the roll-up? On-line/on-premise? Does it work with English? What is the base chosen language? More info, please. :)

Comment: On-premise, roll-up 6. The base language is English - works fine. But when the user switch the language - you can see the image. From the CRM forums, someone told me that this happens also with French.

Comment: This has happened suddenly in the production server, no customizations were made recently. I have removed all customizations and reinstalled the language packs - the issue remains.

Comment: Another attempt - on a test server, fresh install, I have deployed our customizations and language packs and it works fine. But I cannot reinstall the production server.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get to the problem you have. I tried Russian and French but can't the behavior. Why can't you reinstall the server?

Comment: More likely - I am lazy and I don't want to reinstall it because of countless customizations, some unsupported, but I will think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue on my server so I'd guess it's a localized problem at **your** installation. You might be just of of luck and you'll have to reinstall the production environment.

I'd suggest that you create a shadow organization on the same server and copy over the data. For the users, there wont be any difference (seemingly).

Comment: Thanks, I will try with shadow organization.

Comment: Good luck. If you're good, accept one of the replies as an answer. And please get back to SO telling how well/badly it went.

Comment: Will do, in the next couple of days.

Comment: You can just register a new organization for free on-line (30 days trial).

Comment: I have installed new server, applied all customization and localization - everything is rendering fine. My best guess is that we somehow corrupted the language strings.

Comment: @dbrmr Yes, I'm prone to agree on that. The interesting thing is not what you achieved but **how**, so that others can avoid the wrong steps. Can you think of anything?

Comment: I have no idea. But generally when localizing software I am very afraid of using comas, quotes or double quotes in the strings, because of many issues that I have had in the past. If that was the case, I think that there would be some javascript exceptions, but there are not.

Comment: Another option is - there might be bug in the js/css code for the dropdown menu. All html and strings are there, but when the menu is shown, most of the screen turns white. I am not good in js/css, but I think that in order to render the menu in top of other elements it should play with z-index, the menu either brings itself at the top or takes everything else to the back. Either way when the menu is visible, every element, that has localized string goes white, but when I mouse over (hover) it appears, and when I select with the mouse I can see the text.

Answer (score 1):

the issue depends on MUI pack rollup missing or not.

So you have to check if your server has the same rollup equals than your MUI pack rollup.

So if you have 3 languages after the base language, all these languages must have MUI pack rollup equals server rollup.

I hope you understand,

Alberto

Comment: Thanks Alberto, for your input. But we have already reinstalled everything. If this happens in the future, I will try to fix it this way.